# Checking a virtual tour URL is still valid

Tags: google-maps

Say I have got a virtual tour embed iframe like this (this example is the inside of a restaurant):

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1431365705636!6m8!1m7!1sO9bKUs8Jy-gAAAQZFe9qpg!2m2!1d52.955261!2d-1.149388!3f158.39!4f0!5f0.7820865974627469" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

What happens if a virtual tour is removed or taken down? For example if a location changed hands or was refurbished? Is there a way I can check it is still valid and there is something there?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not tell if you are using iframe, but not if you use javascript.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview